# How to change setting of printing package preview dilaoge in flutter and when the user changes the printer settings print all selected setting?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, printing

In Android img preview-> [image printing preview in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpyBR.png)

In Android img page size preview->[page size list showing in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZWG5.png)

In IOS preview of page size [IOS preview of page size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcx0a.png)

package which i am using   `

> printing: ^5.9.1
>
> pdf: ^3.8.1

to priview image

```
 await Printing.layoutPdf(
  // [onLayout] will be called multiple times
  // when the user changes the printer or printer settings
  onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) {
    // Any valid Pdf document can be returned here as a list of int
    return doc.save();
  },
);
```

How can we change the printing preview default page size  ISO A4 to A4 and remove unnecessary item and after changing any setting on run time print selected values like
if user has selected A4 print A4,if user has selected color B/W print black & white ?